# Coldfusion - Comma delimiter with comma inside value

Tags: sql, list, coldfusion

I am building a list using SQL data and I am trying to make each value of the list as: `'value1',value2','value,4'` and so on.
My problem is that I am using this code:

```
(
    SELECT COUNT(ns.ticket)
    FROM ns_trade ns
    WHERE ns.[login]=mt.[login]
        AND 
        <cfif qGetCommentsAccounting.recordCount gt 0> 
            ns.COMMENT IN ('#listChangeDelims(qGetCommentsAccounting.list_comments, "','")#')
        <cfelse>
            1=2
        </cfif>
)as no_of_tickets_accounting
```

which is works perfect EXCEPT when my value has comma inside like `'value,4'`.
Any suggestions how to solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both queries work on the same database, it would be way more *KISS* to put them together. Usually, you should try to do as much as possible within your database.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(ns.ticket)
FROM 
    ns_trade ns
WHERE 
    ns.[login] = mt.[login]
AND 
    ns.COMMENT IN 
        (
        SELECT 
            comment
        FROM 
            tbl_comment 
        WHERE 
            report_type = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.type#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
        AND 
            report_id = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.report_id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
        )
```

Comment: It might be even simpler to join the tables.

Comment: @DanBracuk To prevent another hasty answer of mine, are you sure a simple join would give the same result? The subquery could have double values for the [comment] column ...

Comment: @StefanBraun - It depends on the data and desired results. A JOIN would probably be more appropriate for a one-to-one relationship and a subquery for one-to-many. However, if the input contains multiple values the appropriate filter would be `WHERE Col IN ( <cfqueryparam list="true"....> )` rather than equals.

Comment: @Leigh `cfqueryparam list="true" `could be _dangerous_ with arbitrary strings ... you can not assume that your delimiter is not within the input data.

Comment: (Edit) @StefanBraun -  Sure, (unescaped) delimiters should not be present in the data itself - or they are not really delimiters ;-) However, cfqueryparam allows you to specify which delimiter should be used (see the "separator" attribute).  That said, now that I have had more coffee I see what you are suggesting (duh!).  You are correct.  The asker could avoid lists altogether by matching on record ID's only.

Answer (score 0):

I fix the problem changing my query to:

```
<cfquery name="qGetComments" datasource="#application.dsn#">
            SELECT (STUFF((SELECT ',' +CHAR(39) +CAST(comment as varchar(50)) +CHAR(39)
                               FROM tbl_comment
                               WHERE report_type = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.type#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
                               AND report_id = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.report_id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
                               FOR XML PATH('')),1, 1, '')) as list_comments
        </cfquery>
```

where CHR(39) is the single quote and later on the other query (wich is inside an `cfsavecontent`):

```
(SELECT COUNT(ns.ticket)
                          FROM ns_trade ns
                          WHERE ns.[login]=mt.[login]
                          AND <cfif qGetCommentsAccounting.recordCount gt 0> ns.COMMENT IN (#qGetCommentsAccounting.list_comments#)
                              <cfelse>
                                1=2
                              </cfif>)as no_of_tickets_accounting
```

and execute it with `PreserveSingleQuotes()`

Comment: Is there a reason you must use separate queries instead of using a JOIN or subquery as suggested? You should avoid using `PreserveSingleQuotes` when possible, because it will make the query vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: PreserveSingleQuotes has it's time and place.  This just isn't it.

Comment: Like Evaluate(), `PreserveSingleQuotes` is used far more frequently than it is actually needed.. and usage comes with some security risks. Personally, I have never found a need for it in a CF app.

Comment: I am using `PreserveSingleQuotes` when I am building a query a in `CFSaveContent` and I want to execute it later. The reason which the 2 queries are seperated is because the first one is used by other queries also.

Comment: @BlackM Then do the first one additionally. Just because you need the results again does not justify those "dirty" hacks.